# Empty JSON Response from Controller in C# Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I am learning about building web APIs in C#.

I am testing my controller, however I am getting an empty `JSON` response.

This is my controller

```
public class ClassInfoController : ApiController
{
    private ClassRepository classRepo = new ClassRepository();

    public IList<string> getClassListByTerm(string termID)
    {
        List<string> classList = classRepo.getClassListByTerm(termID);

        return classList;
    }
```

This is my repository class which queries my Entity model

```
public class ClassRepository : IClass
{

    private cet_databaseEntities db = new cet_databaseEntities();

    public List<string> getClassListByTerm(string termID)
    {
        List<string> result = (from t in db.classCodeLookup
                where t.termID == termID
                orderby t.@class ascending
                select t.@class).ToList<string>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have debugged my controller and when the API call is made, this repository class returns no data to the controller i.e. an empty `list`. However, the reason I am confused, is that when I use the following test code on the repository class

```
public class ClassRepositoryTests
{
    ClassRepository testRepo = new ClassRepository();

    [TestMethod()]
    public void getClassListByTermTest()
    {
        List<string> output = testRepo.getClassListByTerm("316a");
        foreach (string className in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(className);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the result from the repository class I expect.

Why am I having this issue?

Comment: Assuming the same input is given to `termID`, this only leads to the conclusion that your client side is not properly sending you the data in the correct manner. If you will show us the client side code + ajax call, we could help you further.

Comment: Questions: What the request you are making to the api?
set breakpoint in getClassListByTerm, gets there?
return hardcoded List<string> with data: new List<string> { "yes", "this is data", "xD" }; 
Post results

Comment: From your explanation, I think there is nothing wrong with the Web API. Can you please provide more details about how you are testing your controller? Did you check what termID is being passed when testing the controller? Please double check the connection strings for the test project and Web Api project?

Comment: I get data when I hard code the following in the method body:            `List<string> classList = new List<string> { "test", "testData" };`
`return classList;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the automatic API documentation provided by a Web API project in Visual Studio told me that I should call my controller from the browser with the following: `http://localhost:51520/api/ClassInfo?termID={316a}`. Unbeknownst to me, this meant the `{}` stayed with the `316a` - I thought they were just like the parentheses used in a method signature for receiving a parameter, but I presume they are used for passing `list`/`json` to a method (not relevant in this case). This meant that when my repository query ran, it returned nothing because I was not looking for the string `{316a}`.

If I call the API with the following address `http://localhost:51520/api/ClassInfo?termID=316a` it works because the string `316a` gets passed to the query.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attribute to your API method

```
[HttpGet]
public List<string> getClassListByTerm([FromUri]string termID)
```

or you can use another class object for request data.
I mean

```
 public class TermData
 {
     //use if nessassry [JsonProperty("TermId")]
     public string TermId {get;set;}
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public List<string> getClassListByTerm([FromUri]TermData data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a class inheriting from DynamicObject, and that would only return empty JSON (while XML seemed to return properly).

In my case, I was able to remove the DynamicObject inheritance and JSON serialization started working.

```
//didn't serialize to json, but xml worked
public MyClass : DynamicObject, IMyClass { //... }

//works for json and xml
public MyClass : IMyClass { //... }
```

Unfortunately, I didn't have a chance to look into why `DynamicObject` breaks JSON serialization.