# Web API not returning any result data in EF6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, rest, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a `web api` in `visual studio 2015` using `MySQL` database. The table created is dummy as I have entered dummy data in it. Till now the web-service/web API is just for testing method. Below are the steps I have done so far.

**1. Created a model (DB first)**

```
public partial class MetersInfo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string meter_msn { get; set; }
    public string meter_kwh { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Created a repository**

```
interface IMeterRepository
{
    IEnumerable<MetersInfo> GetAll();

    MetersInfo Get(int id);

}

public class MeterInfoRepository : IMeterRepository
{
    private List<MetersInfo> m_info = new List<MetersInfo>();

    public IEnumerable<MetersInfo>GetAll()
    {
        return m_info;
    }

    public MetersInfo Get(int id)
    {
        return m_info.Find(m => m.id == id);
    }
}
```

**3. Created a controller**

```
public class MetersInfoController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IMeterRepository repo = new MeterInfoRepository();

    public IEnumerable<MetersInfo> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return repo.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Below is **Web.config**

```
<add name="MeterEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MeterModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MeterModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MeterModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=accurate_dev&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I run my API, I got nothing just an empty `JSON`

While debugging it I have found that the `List` is empty. I have also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667892/empty-json-response-from-controller-in-c-sharp-web-api) question. But still couldn't able to resolve my issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: All your `GetAll()` method in `MeterInfoRepository` is return `m_info` which is an empty collection (`new List<MetersInfo>()`) - where do you populate it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the table is non-empty. I have added some dummy values in it and then try to convert it into the list.

Comment: But where is you code for connecting to your database and reading the data (all you have shown is a connection string)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Are you talking about this ? ` public virtual DbSet<MetersInfo> meters_info_dev { get; set; }`

Comment: That is just defining your context. You need to call the database and get the values via your database context